# Is there any way to make my Macbook automatically subtitle the sound output?

Tags: audio, text-to-speech

Suppose I'm in a Skype meeting in a room with people speaking plain English, but I'm having some trouble to hear/understand what they are saying. It would be very useful to have a subtitle, so I can read it in case I miss some word. Is that possible to do on my Macbook?

Comment: If you're having trouble deciphering what someone is saying, a machine is going to have no chance at all.

Comment: @Tetsujin no I actually have a lot of trouble hearing English as I'm used only to write and read, and written English isn't phonetical. Yes that is bizarre but I have no idea how to say the things I write. A mediocre, live speech-to-text app would probably help me a lot.

Comment: You can make a Mac app with the new SKSpeechRecognizer class.